# problems deploying node.js application

Tags: node.js, express, appfog

I'm having trouble deploying node.js application to appfog, according to the instruction on appfog i made a new package.json file with the next content:

```
{
    "name":"<my app name>",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":""
     }
}
```

and a new app.js file with the next content:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from AppFog');
});
app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
```

then i wrote the command:

```
$ npm install
```

and got the next warning:

```
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
```

and when i try to push my app to appfog i get the next message:

```
No such file or directory - /Applications/Flip Player.app
```

what am i missing here? am i doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the WARN, as it's just a signal to package maintainers that they should add a Readme.

Your real bug is that your app is missing Flip Player. Somehow, you've added Flip Player to your repository, or indicated it was required with adding it.

If you just started your project, I would try blowing away your git repository and then creating a new one, this time being careful to leave Flip Player out.